# how to get the string array of activities c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

How can I get the string array of my activities with c#. I used to do it with java this way:

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.activities)
```

Thks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [example](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/auto_complete/), it should be:

```
string[] countries = Resources.GetStringArray (Resource.array.countries_array);
```

Having defined

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="countries_array">
        <item>Bahrain</item>
        <item>Bangladesh</item>
        <item>Barbados</item>
        <item>Belarus</item>
        <item>Belgium</item>
        <item>Belize</item>
        <item>Benin</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```